# hiding Tabbar during navigation

Tags: flutter, dart

My main screen has got AppBar and BottomNavigationBar. if I navigate to screen 2 BottomNavigationBar is staying. It is perfect for me.

But I would like to remove the Tabbar for screen 2. Because the content of Screen 2 is irrelevant with the TabbarMenu.

I am going to screen 2 from screen 1 `return Page2` like this:

```
Widget showPage(int selectedPage) {
    if (selectedPage == 0) {
      return const NewsView(id: '1');
    } else if (selectedPage == 1) {
      return const Settings();
```

any help?

Comment: Please share more code related to your problem.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/m0PdD6Lc